# MongoDB findOne failing SECOND TIME in node.js app... ERROR connecting to: mongodb://

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

This is happening on a node.js app.

I'm trying to see if one of the recipes URLs in the hrefs array exist in the MongoDB. The following code works the first time it runs, but then fails 30 seconds later when it runs again(setInterval).

The first time it successfully returns yes or no for each URL in the array:

```
yes
no
yes
yes
yes
yes
```

Thirty seconds later, when it runs a second time:

```
ERROR connecting to: mongodb://<the url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<the url here]]
ERROR connecting to: mongodb://<the url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<the url here]]
ERROR connecting to: mongodb://<the url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<the url here]]
ERROR connecting to: mongodb://<the url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<the url here]]
ERROR connecting to: mongodb://<the url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<the url here]]
```

The code:

```
var mongoDB;
function connectToDb(done){
  mongo.connect(uristring, options, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
         console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
         console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
         mongoDb = db;
         done();
      }
  });
}

function checkHREFS(recipes) {
   var recipeCollection = mongoDb.collection('recipeURL');
   recipefCollection.findOne({
      'recipe_url': { $in: recipes }
   }, function (err, recipe) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('ERROR:' + err);
      } else if (!href) {
         console.log('no');
      } else {
         console.log('yes');
         return true;
      }
   });
}

connectToDb(function(){
   checkHREFS(hrefs);
});
```

UPDATE: This didn't help, and the console.log in the if(mongDB) never gets called.

```
var mongoDB;
function connectToDb(done){
   if(mongoDB) { console.log('already connected'); return done(); }
   mongo.connect(uristring, options, function (err, db) {
      if (err) {
         console.log ('ERROR connecting to: ' + uristring + '. ' + err);
      } else {
         console.log ('Succeeded connected to: ' + uristring);
         mongoDb = db;
         done();
      }
  });
}
```

I get a huge list of errors that switch between the following two errors:

```
ERROR connecting to: <url here>. Error: failed to connect to [<number here>.mongolab.com:<port here>]

ERROR connecting to: <url here>. Error: No valid replicaset instance servers found
```

Another function I have in the same file works fine:

```
connectToDb(function(){
   recipesToDB(recipes);
});
function recipesToDB(recipes) {
   mongoDb.createCollection('recipes', function(err, collection) {});
   var recipeCollection = mongoDb.collection('recipes');

   recipeCollection.insert(recipes, {continueOnError: true}, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
         console.log('ERROR:' + err);
      } else {
         console.log('*******************************************');
         console.log('********Succeeded inserted recipes********');
         console.log('*******************************************');
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be opening a new connection pool each time you need to call `checkHREFS`; you should just open a single pool for the application during startup.

Comment: You could add a line at the top of connectToDb that does something like: `if(mongoDB) { return done(); }`

Comment: @PeterVC, updated original post with what I tried from your suggestion. Still no luck :(.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is strange, because another function where I insert data on a timer works fine... but using findOne with this array breaks after it runs once.

Comment: Are you sure `uristring` and `options` are not changing between calls?

Comment: Okay, ends up the variable answer suggested used mongoDB as the variable, which must have already been used or something.

Changing it to myDB works :).

Comment: @PeterVC, if you answer the question I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your request.
Changing it to myDB.